# ExoPlayer playerView layout

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I'm using exoplayer to setup a video player in a fragment. In the fragment, the video is on the top followed by a textView and a button. But the player controller overlapped with the video like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsCLt.png)

Below is my layout xml for the fragment:

```
    <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerView_step_video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_step_description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/playerView_step_video"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/playerView_step_video"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/playerView_step_video" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_next_step"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/next_step"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_step_description"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_step_description" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: you can take google exo player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and change it.. remove scrollview.

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
    android:id="@+id/playerView_step_video"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: The result is same. Also according to the http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/SimpleExoPlayerView.html, SimpleExoPlayerView is deprecated, that's why i'm using PlayerView

Comment: you remove scroll view .

Comment: i think scroll then it hide video.